# How to replace a button and re position it dynamically?

Tags: swt, jface

I have a text box and a add button next to it, when I click on add button I am able to add a text box and delete button next to it. Now I want the add button on the first row to be changed to delete and the add button should be re-positioned below two rows, when the second row delete button  is clicked (the second row is deleted )the add button should go back to the first row and replace delete button. It should look like following.

[image]

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `Composite` as a container of sorts, you can add and remove from it allowing everything outside to remain in the correct order. By reserving the space, the delete button is always below the contents of the container.

> I have a text box and a add button next to it, when I click on add button I am able to add a text box and delete button next to it

For example, if we have a small `Shell` with an add `Button` as you mentioned, and an empty space to add the `Text` widgets to:

```
final Composite baseComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
baseComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
baseComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

final Composite rowsContainerComposite = new Composite(baseComposite, SWT.BORDER);
rowsContainerComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
rowsContainerComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

final Button addButton = new Button(baseComposite, SWT.PUSH);
addButton.setText("Add");
```

[image]

*(For now the empty space is grabbing all available space, but you can change that as needed)*

When adding rows, you can add to the `rowsContainerComposite`:

```
addButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
        new Row(rowsContainerComposite);
        rowsContainerComposite.layout();
    }
});
```

A sample `Row` class:

```
public class Row {

    final Composite baseComposite;

    public Row(final Composite parent) {
        baseComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        baseComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        baseComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        final Text text = new Text(baseComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        final Button deleteButton = new Button(baseComposite, SWT.PUSH);
        deleteButton.setText("Delete");
        deleteButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
                baseComposite.dispose();
                parent.layout();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

[image]

> when the second row delete button is clicked (the second row is deleted )the add button should go back to the first row

Then when deleted, rows will shift back appropriately:

[image]

> the add button should be re-positioned below two rows

The idea is that by using the "container" composite, you're reserving that space to add and remove the rows from. The delete button will always be below the rows as they are added and removed.

---

Full example:

```
public class AddDeleteButtonTest {

    private static class Row {

        final Composite baseComposite;

        public Row(final Composite parent) {
            baseComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
            baseComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
            baseComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

            final Text text = new Text(baseComposite, SWT.BORDER);
            text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

            final Button deleteButton = new Button(baseComposite, SWT.PUSH);
            deleteButton.setText("Delete");
            deleteButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
                    baseComposite.dispose();
                    parent.layout();
                }

            });
        }

    }

    private final Display display;
    private final Shell shell;

    public AddDeleteButtonTest() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        final Composite baseComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        baseComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        baseComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        final Composite rowsContainerComposite = new Composite(baseComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        rowsContainerComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        rowsContainerComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        final Button addButton = new Button(baseComposite, SWT.PUSH);
        addButton.setText("Add");
        addButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
                new Row(rowsContainerComposite);
                rowsContainerComposite.layout();
            }

        });
    }

    public void run() {
        shell.setSize(200, 200);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        new AddDeleteButtonTest().run();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you avojak, but I need something like above mentioned images

Comment: @user7999545 This pretty much answers what you asked, we aren't here to give you the exact code to replicate your picture. Styling the text and buttons is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: @user7999545 Those pictures weren't part of your question when I answered, and as Greg said, I'm not going to write all your code for you. You should be able to follow a nearly identical approach to get what you want.

Comment: @ avojak  Thank you again for the code snippet I was able to accomplish what I want and sorry for asking again, as I was little confused initially since I am new to this.

Comment: @user7999545 No need to apologize - glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I did the same in one of my project. The code is bit complicated to do in Jface/SWT. Adding and removing widgets on composite will be bit heavy task. This will reduce UI performance.

If you use Jface tableviewer instead of creating composite, you will get better UI performance and good look as well.  In table viewer in one column you can show textboxes and in one column you can show buttons. You can write table column Editing support/label providers to show the buttons.

With this approach you will be able show buttons for all rows or when you click on any cell you want to add or delete.

I can't share the code snippet right now, due to some reasons, but if you need I will share it on weekends